# using replace() to grab id from each link stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The list of links is taken from the input while each link in the input is separated by a space so it can later be split in the code. I tried to use the following code, the goal is to result in only the id part of of all the links in an array. But instead it only results in the id of the first link and the rest of the links remain unchanged.

here are two sample links:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jTZ37iVWdb6MEs1HQzFtkKaOmEVNoG9n/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QlwvBmXzO56Prq4WLERS4tpD2Kcp2yOr/view?usp=sharing
```

here is the jquery:

```
$("#checklist").on("click", function () {

  var value = $("#uploadlist").val();
  var arr= value.split(" ")

  $.each(arr, function(key, list){

  if (list.startsWith("https://drive.google.com/file/d/") & 
     list.endsWith("/view?usp=sharing")) {

     var id1 = list.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "");
     var id= id1.replace("/view?usp=sharing", "");

    console.log(id)
})
```

i have also tried using:

```
    var id= list.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "").replace("/view? 
    usp=sharing","");
    console.log(id);
```

Comment: Why do you split your upload list by space characters (`value.split(" ")`)? If you want to match parts of a URL, you should better split by slash (value.split("/")) and then retrieve the ID from the URL part you need.

Comment: i split it by space characters so the if statement can check if each element of the array starts with `"https://drive.google.com/file/d/"` and includes `"/viewusp=sharing"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split by `\nhttp`
2. Find ID

```js
var links=`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jTZ37iVWdb6MEs1HQzFtkKaOmEVNoG9n/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QlwvBmXzO56Prq4WLERS4tpD2Kcp2yOr/view?usp=sharing
`;

links = links
  .split(/\nhttp/)
  .map((link)=>{
    return link.replace(/(.*?)file\/d\//, "").replace(/\/view(.*?)+\n/,"");
  });

console.log(links);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found your error:

you wrote:

```
list.endsWith("/viewusp=sharing"))
```

instead of

```
list.endsWith("/view?usp=sharing"))
```

It would be a good idea to put the beginning and ending of the URL in a variable and not repeat them.

```
$("#checklist").on("click", function () {

    const start = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/"
    const end = "view?usp=sharing"
    var value = $("#uploadlist").val();
    var arr= value.split(" ")

    $.each(arr, function(key, list){
        if (list.startsWith(start) & list.endsWith(end)) {
            const id = list.replace(start,"").replace(end,"");
            console.log(id);
        }
    });

    //The rest of your code here

});
```

Comment: If it's a typo error, why does it work with the first URL but not the rest?

Comment: Oh opps, that was just a typo. That does not happen in the actual code i am trying to run. Thankyou :) i'll fix it.